# How to redirect on particular page in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, redirect

```
<?php 
if($result_array['ACK']== 'Success')
{
wp_redirect( get_page_by_title( 'thank-you' ) );
}else{ 
//redirect like php
 header("Location : http://localhost/mysite/faq"); 
} ?>
```

My query is working but I have no idea that how I simply redirect in my page and display any my page content data in wordpress. So please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should pass the actual **title** into that function, not the slug:

```
wp_redirect( get_page_by_title( 'Thank You' ) );
```